# hystrix javanica collapser did not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix

I am using hystrix javanica collapser in spring boot, but I found it did not work, my code just like this below:

service class:

```
public class TestService {

    @HystrixCollapser(batchMethod = "getStrList")
    public Future<String> getStr(String id) {
         System.out.println("single");
         return null;
     }

     @HystrixCommand
     public List<String> getStrList(List<String> ids) {
         System.out.println("batch,size=" + ids.size());

         List<String> strList = Lists.newArrayList();
         ids.forEach(id -> strList.add("test"));
         return strList;
     }
 }
```

where I use:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          TestService testService = new TestService();

          HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();

          Future<String> f1= testService.getStr("111");
          Future<String> f2= testService.getStr("222");

          try {
              Thread.sleep(3000);
              System.out.println(f1.get()); // nothing printed
              System.out.println(f2.get()); // nothing printed
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }

          context.shutdown();
      }
```

It printed 3 `single` instead of 1 `batch`.

I want to know what's wrong with my code, a valid example is better.

Comment: You aren't using anything. You are simply creating a new instance of the `TestService` whereas you should use Spring to bootstrap the application and create a proper instance of the bean.

Comment: This is just a sample, it did not work when I use it in spring-boot.

Comment: If you you use the same code in Spring Boot then it won't work. Post some actual code instead of derived code, this code won't work. You must use the Spring Boot provided instance, if you don't do that, even in a Spring Boot application, then it won't work (Spring Boot creates a proxy around the actual object, if you don't use that proxy it simply won't work). Next to that does the Spring Cloud Hystrix out-of-the-box support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a  hystrix javanica sample on the internet, So I have to read the source code to solve this problem, now it's solved, and this is my summary:

when you use hystrix(javanica) collapser in spring-boot, you have to:

1. Defined a `hystrixAspect` spring bean and import `hystrix-strategy.xml`;
2. Annotate single method with `@Hystrix Collapser` annotate batch method with `@HystrixCommand`;
3. Make your single method need 1 parameter(ArgType) return Future ,  batch method need List return List and make sure size of args be equal to size of return.
4. Set hystrix properties `batchMethod, scope`, if you want to collapse requests from multiple user threads, you must set the scope to GLOBAL;
5. Before you submit a single request, you must init the hystrix context with `HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext()`, and `shutdown` the context when your request finish;